# global variable not working in php class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

```
class Database
{
    public $connect = "";

    public function connect()
    {
       $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1521", "phone");
       ini_set('default_charset', "UTF-8");
       mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");
       header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
       if ($connect->connect_error) {
           die('Not connect' . mysqli_connect_error());
       }
    }

    public function insert()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM personal ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        //global $connect;
        $result = $connect->query($sql);//// this here !!!!!!!!
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $tempint = (int)$row['id'];
        $tempint += 1;
    }
}
```

why $connect in insert function not working ?
I added global befor $connect but still not working.
this very simple class for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You syntax is incorrect.

Change this,

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1521", "phone");
```

To,

```
$this->connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1521", "phone");
```

Also,

```
$result = $connect->query($sql);
```

To,

```
$result = $this->connect->query($sql);
```

With the above changes it should fix the issue.

`$connect` has been created in the scope of the class so when you refer to it you need to use `$this`.